# like to modify url parameter for seo using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

I want to encode an URL for SEO of my raw PHP project. I have an URL, for example: `http://dealsinbd.com/bn/member/register/`, that I need to modify for my project.

In the URL you can see that: 1) `bn`, 2) `member`, 3) `register` parameters exist.

Now I want to get the `bn` value in my PHP file with `$_REQUEST['controller']`, `member` value should be accessed with `$_REQUEST['param1']` and `register` value should be accessed with `$_REQUEST['param2']`, and so on ...

Please suggest a solution or a `htaccess` script.

Answer (score 1):

I use rewrites like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

that forward all requests to index.php

index.php then parses the original URL to detect all settings and parameters it needs and then calls the controller.

Comment: thank you for your reply, can i define multiple parameters from htaccess so that i can avoid scripting in index.php to catch parameters. for example: to get the first parameter can i use $_REQUEST['param'], or to get second parameter can i use $_REQUEST['param2'] in index.php without doing any scripting in the index.php.

Comment: I don't know about such possibility. For most developers, htaccess script is a kind of black magic, so keeping as much logic as possible in PHP is good for maintainability of your application. It is easier to debug this way, too.